# Unable to uninstall bundles on Apache services mix (Karaf)

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix, hawtio

When we are trying to uninstall any bundle on servicemix its throws below error but current hawtio version installed is 2.17.5 . Our current servicemix version is 7.0.1 and karaf version is 4.0.9 .

Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=expressco-oms-consoles; type=karaf.feature; version="[0,0.0.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=expressco-oms-consoles)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=0.0.0)(version<=0.0.0))" [caused by: Unable to resolve expressco-oms-consoles/0.0.0: missing requirement [expressco-oms-consoles/0.0.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=hawtio; type=karaf.feature [caused by: Unable to resolve hawtio/2.17.6: missing requirement [hawtio/2.17.6] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=hawtio-core; type=karaf.feature [caused by: Unable to resolve hawtio-core/2.17.6: missing requirement [hawtio-core/2.17.6] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=io.hawt.hawtio-osgi; type=osgi.bundle; version="[2.17.6,2.17.6]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve io.hawt.hawtio-osgi/2.17.6: missing requirement [io.hawt.hawtio-osgi/2.17.6] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=4.0.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))"]]]]

We tried below options:
restarted karaf
restarted server
Tried to uninstall 2.17.5 version and install 2.17.6 version of Hawtio
install scr

Comment: I have had this happen once or twice and in those cases it seemed like internal state of Karaf had messed up somehow and the only way to fix this was to reset karaf completely. This means stopping Karaf, removing the [data](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_directory_structure) folder and starting Karaf again. Depending how your Karaf instance is setup you may have to re-install some features, bundles and etc.